# Converting Vector * to char *

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, char

I'm having a problem converting my pointer to a vector to a `char *`.
Here is my code, what is it that I'm doing wrong?

```
char * Word1 = (*fileRead)[i].c_str();
char * Word2 =  dict[j].c_str();

if(WordCmp(Word1,Word2)
{
    found = true;   
}
```

Here is the function header for `WordCmp()`.

```
int WordCmp(char* Word1, char* Word2);
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
server.cpp:200: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
server.cpp:201: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
```

Comment: owwwwwwww, never heard of `std::string`?

Answer (score 5):

The compiler tells you, that the type of the pointer is a "pointer to a cost char", but you're trying to assign it to a pointer to a (mutable) char.

Replace the first two lines with

```
const char * Word1 = (*fileRead)[i].c_str();
const char * Word2 =  dict[j].c_str();
```

Comment: also change the signature of function `WordCmp` to `int WordCmp(const char * Word1, const char * Word2)`